# How should a React app (or any SPA) interact with a HATEOAS back-end?

Tags: reactjs, hateoas

The basic question is if there should be one HATEOAS entry point per page or one entry point for the entire app?

Most examples I have seen implement a single page with a HATEOAS backend, e.g. a list that is paginated using `prev` and `next` links. But what happens when the app navigates to a different page that has completely different capabilities and needs a different entry point? How does one organize such an app?

**Concrete example**: We have an app with tab navigation. The home tab shows a product catalog so the entry point is `/products` which returns page 1 of products along with pagination links. However, now I click on the orders tab which must show a list of past orders. This page needs a completely different entry point `/orders` which the home tab knows nothing about. In fact, user can directly navigate to the orders tab using a deep link.

How to think about this problem? Are there any examples illustrating an approach?

Comment: Well your premise that the home tab doesn't know about the orders URI is incorrect. If the entry point to your app is `/products` that entry point in the API needs to return all possible links that the client can navigate directly to. You would receive a set of HATEOAS links from the API entry point that includes the `/orders` URI. The last part of your problem is the million dollar question. How can you provide deep links to different parts of your app if you must "discover" the URI's from the entry point, they aren't known ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different ways to solve this. Here's two:

1. The SPA takes context from the uri (such as an id), and uses it to search on the API. The API can describe templated links/actions to search for resources by their id.
2. Instead of doing client-side routing, let the server decide what to render.

We're going more towards #2. If we have a uri such as:

```
https://spa.example/https://api.example/foo/bar
```

We take the path part of this uri and hit the API. Based on what the API responds with, we decide what to render. This means that most of the routing for these kinds of endpoints is delegated to the server, which feels more in line with HATEOAS.

The path part in this case is an entire absolute URI, but we also support relative uris and have a default base uri. So in practice these two uris are equivalent (for our SPA):

```
https://spa.example/https://api.example/foo/bar
https://spa.example/foo/bar
```

We develop & use [ketting](https://github.com/badgateway/ketting) / [react-ketting](https://github.com/badgateway/react-ketting) to do most of the heavy lifting

Comment: Thanks, Evert. I will definitely look at your suggestions.

Comment: @Evert From what I understand, that would decouple the SPA implementation from the backend, from the perspective of the code. But wouldn't it at the same time increase coupling at a semantic level? There might be different frontends for the same backend and they might want to behave differently (maybe one frontend targets the customer support and the other one the customer). When routing is determined by the backend, there's not much freedom for the frontends, right? It would need another backend (or at least middleware) to fix that.

Comment: @Florian you could in that case just add another path segment with some information relevant to the frontend